# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to make a method in the model to handle the database create. But when i run it it says

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it
>   must be defined as a key

```
private function create_users_table()
{
    $this->load->dbforge();
    $this->dbforge->add_field('id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
    $this->dbforge->add_field('email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL');
    $this->dbforge->add_field('password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL');
    $this->dbforge->add_field('created DATETIME NOT NULL');
    $this->dbforge->add_field('last_login DATETIME NOT NULL');
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id',TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table($this->users_table);
}
```

Comment: Try `id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and remove the separate `add_key()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The db forge class in codeigniter identifies id field automatically as primary key.

```
$this->dbforge->add_field('id'); // gives id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help Neit . The answer is: id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Comment: It is because "Passing raw strings as fields cannot be followed by add_key() calls on those fields." as stated in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/forge.html#passing-strings-as-fields).